# Debug Test and Debug All Tests for apex unit tests in VSCodedx

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, debugging, apextestrunresult

Does anyone have a link to the official documentation on this new feature added to VSCode-dx?

Also, any tips on using this feature would be appreciated.

*What I've tried so far: I've tried the feature and all it does is to run the unit test(s) and changing the focus to the debug console panel,  but I don't see any debug file being pulled down nor any debug session is activated.*

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Did you start the debugging session? You need to do that before debugging.

Comment: @sfdcfox you are absolutely correct sir, thanks much for your helpful comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sfdcfox says in his comment, I needed to first turn on the replay debugger and then run either Debug All Tests or Debug Test. (To turn on the replay debugger in vscode, command+shif+p/control+shift+p and type "turn on replay" and you'll see that option appearing).

Now if you click on this feature, (which shows up right next to the Run Test at the top of each unit test in your test class), it'll run the test(s) and starts a debugging session (with the Apex Replay Debugger). If you already have set any breakpoints it will jump-start into the first one.

This is much more convenient than having to pull down the log file and execute the debug command on the file, which is the method I've been using up to this point.

I hope this helps! Thanks to @sfdcfox for pretty much giving me this answer in his helpful comment.